# Using Regex to remove script tags

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to use a Regex expression I've found in this website and it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

**Input string**:

```
sFetch = "123<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n\t\tfunction utmx_section(){}function utmx(){}\n\t\t(function()})();\n\t</script>456";
```

**Regex**:

```
sFetch = Regex.Replace(sFetch, "<script.*?>.*?</script>", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: You should not use regex to try to *parse* HTML : HTML is not quite regular ;; instead, you should use an HTML Parser -- like based on DOM.

Comment: It looks like you haven't read this article explaining how to use regex to parse HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: See S.Mark's answer. But all in all, it's not a good regex, and anyway regexes aren't really suited for this.

Comment: @Pascal MARTIN: He don't want to parse, just remove some text. Don't see a difference?

Comment: Tim and Pascal are correct. Whenever I write code to look for dangerous HTML constructs, I always use a DOM, never a regex. If for *no other reason* than there are so many ways to escape HTML it's next to impossible to regex.

Answer (score 9):

Add `RegexOptions.Singleline`

```
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline
```

And that will never work on follow one.

```
<script
>
alert(1)
</script
/**/
>
```

So, Find a HTML parser like [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks.
Any other recommendations about C# packages like Agility to parse HTML???

Comment: `Singleline` is the option you want; it allows `.` to match linefeeds.  `Multiline` causes `$` and `^` to match before and after (respectively) linefeeds; it's irrelevant here.

Answer (score 8):

The reason the regex fails is that your input has `newlines` and the meta char `.` does not match it.

To solve this you can use the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option as S.Mark says, or you can change the regex to:

```
"<script[\d\D]*?>[\d\D]*?</script>"
```

which used `[\d\D]` instead of `.`.

`\d` is any digit and `\D` is any non-digit, so `[\d\D]` is a digit or a non-digit which is effectively any char.

Comment: Thanks. 
Is this a solution also for nested script tags?

Answer (score 5):

If you actually want to sanitize a html string (and you're using .NET) then take a look at the [Microsoft Web Protection Library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/):

```
Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(untrustedHtml);
```

There's a description [here](http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2010/03/microsofts-anti-xss-library.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit shorter:

```
 "<script[^<]*</script>"
```

or

```
"<[^>]*>[^>]*>"
```

Comment: Thanks. 
Is this a solution also for nested script tags?

Comment: Yes, absolutely because scripts are never nested.

Comment: They can be nested in a way, actually. For example if someone assigns variable like  `var a = "<script>somenestedscript</script>";` inside of it.

Comment: var a = "<script>somenestedscript</script>"; can never happen this will brak JS itself... then it would be like  var a = "<script>somenestedscript</scr" + "ipt>";