# Remove tag and content in between using REGEX/PHP

Tags: php, regex

I've seen this question asked a few times on stackoverflow, with no resoundingly wonderful answer.
The answer always seems to be "don't use regex," without any *examples* of a better alternative.

For my purposes this will not be done for validation, but after the fact stripping.

I need to strip out all `script` tags including any content that may be between them.

Any suggestions on the best REGEX way to do this?

EDIT: PREEMPTIVE RESPONSE: I can't use HTML Purifier nor the DOMXPath feature of PHP.

Comment: Maybe related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505957/using-regex-to-remove-script-tags

Comment: Consider reading this very popular thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason REGEX for HTML is considered evil, is because it can (usually) easily be broken, forcing you to repeatedly rethink your pattern. If for instance you're matching

```
<script>.+</script>
```

It could be broken easily with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

If you use

```
<script.+/script>
```

It can also be easily broken with

```
< script>...
```

There's no end for this. If you can't use any of the methods you've stated, you could try `strip_tags`, but it takes a **whitelist** as a parameter, not a blacklist, meaning you'll need to manually allow every single tag you want to allow.

If all else fail, you could resort to RegEx, what I came up with is this

```
<\s*script.*/script>
```

But I bet someone around here could probably come and break that too.

Comment: Thanks! Like I said above, it's not about validation, but removal of code that already exists.